# calling a method through an instance is throwing a stackOverFlow Error

Tags: java, object, stack-overflow

I am working on the following scenario where I create an instance of a class and call a method on that instance.It ends up giving me a stackOverFlow Error. My code:

```
public class test {
    test t = new test();
    public  void show(){
    System.out.println("df");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    test t = new test();
    t.show();
}
```

Comment: Every instance of `test` creates a new instance of `test` on initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This throws a `StackOverflowException` because every `test` has the line

```
test t = new test()
```

which will create a new `test`, which will call that same line of code again, which will... you can see how this creates an infinite chain of calls.

You should just remove that line. It would not be needed even if it did what you wanted it to since you already create a new `test` inside your main method.

Answer (score 1):

You have a bad **recursive call** on instantiating `test` instances inside class `test`. It keeps instantiating new instances until no heap space left.  When you have `StackOverflowError` the first thing you need to check is whether anywhere in your code called itself repeatly or not.

Answer (score -3):

Why you create that new instance of class inside the class ? Delete Test t = new test(); inside Test class and try again

Comment: The way this is written it should be a comment. Please read [answer].

Comment: I'm on the phone and i can't see the button to add a comment to his post. I wanted to comment but i didnt found the button. I m using Stack Exchange app

Comment: You do not have the necessary reputation to add a comment yet.  If you abuse the system and post comments as answers you will just delay achieving the rep required.  You could have written that as an answer, explaining why the StackOverflow occurred (but someone else already did).

Comment: Ok, i understand it now. Thanks !

Comment: I suggest you delete this answer (to avoid getting any more downvotes) and concentrate on writing some good answers to get your rep up to where you can post comments (50).

Comment: I cant delete the answer by myself.